# Update Kendo UI Datasource

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm currently working on a project in which I am using Spring MVC in conjunction with the Kendo UI jQuery library (the latest version). The problem that I am having is updating the datasource of the kendo grid inline locally(kendo datasource) as well as remotely. I used the synch and set methods of the datasource object but neither of these worked.

My jQuery code:

```js
/*global $:false */

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    var request;
   
    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip();

    

    var applicationDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/appinfo/findApplications",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "/appinfo/submit",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: "/appinfo/updateApplication",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "/appinfo/deleteApplication",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "applicationId",
                    fields: {
                        applicationId: {type: "number"},
                        applicationName: {type: "string"},
                        url: {type: "string"},
                        serverName: {type: "string"},
                        environmentName: {type: "string"},
                        ipAddress: {type: "string"},
                        genericUserName: {type: "string"},
                        genericPassword: {type: "string"}
                    }
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }

                if (operation == "destroy" && options.models) {
                    console.log("Delete worked");
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(data.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 10
    });




    var applicationGrid = $("#applicationsGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: applicationDataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 600,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        toolbar: [
            {name: "create", text: "Add New Application"}
        ],
        columnMenu: true,
        editable: {
            update: true,
            destroy: true,
            create: true,
            mode: "inline",
            confirmation: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?"
        },
        columns: [
            {field: "applicationName", title: "Application Name"},
            {field: "url", title: "URL"},
            {field: "serverName", title: "Server", editor: serverDropDownEditor, width: "300px"},
            {field: "environmentName", title: "Environment", editor: environmentDropDownEditor, width: "300px"},
            {field: "ipAddress", title: "Database", editor: databaseIpAddressDropDownEditor, width: "300px"},
            {field: "genericUserName", title: "Default Username"},
            {field: "genericPassword", title: "Default Password"},
            {title: "Modify", command: ["edit" , "destroy"]}
        ],
        edit: function (e) {           
            var dataItem = applicationDataSource.at(e.currentTarget);
            console.log("DataSource Count: " + applicationDataSource.total());
        },
        save: function (e) {
            var dataItem = applicationDataSource.at(e.currentTarget);          
            console.log("DataSource Count: " + applicationDataSource.total());
            console.log("The  model on save: " + e.model.applicationName);
            applicationDataSource.sync();
        },
        create: function (e) {
            console.log("Create this: " + e.values);
            applicationDataSource.insert(e.model);
            applicationDataSource.sync();
        },
        delete: function (e) {
            console.log("Delete this: " + e.model);
            applicationDataSource.remove(e.model);
        }
    });


    function serverDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required data-text-field="serverName" data-value-field="serverId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                optionLabel: " - Select - ",
                dataTextField: "serverName",
                dataValueField: "serverId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/appinfo/findServers",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    function environmentDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required data-text-field="environmentName" data-value-field="environmentId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                optionLabel: " - Select - ",
                dataTextField: "environmentName",
                dataValueField: "environmentId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/appinfo/findEnvironments",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    function databaseIpAddressDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required data-text-field="ipAddress" data-value-field="databaseInfoId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                optionLabel: " - Select - ",
                dataTextField: "ipAddress",
                dataValueField: "databaseInfoId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/appinfo/findDatabases",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
});
```

BTW.... I am using the latest version of Kendo-UI Web.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really say what your actual problem is, but my guess is that it isn't making any network requests to the server.
I think this is because you have `batch` mode enabled on the DataSource, so it isn't going to automatically send changes to the server unless either the Grid tells it to, or you manually call `.sync()`

I see you are trying to call `.sync()` in the `save` and `create` event handlers, but you don't need to do that. The grid will sync the datasource when the Save button is clicked. However, you don't have a Save button. Normally you would add one to the Grid's toolbar:

```
toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
```

Then you will get all 3 buttons on the grid toolbar. You would make your edits to all your data rows, then click "Save", and the grid will call `.sync()` on your DataSource for you. This will also trigger the `save` event callback, but it doesn't look like your callback is doing anything but logging the data to the console. You don't need to call `.sync()` in the event callbacks.

The [Grid : Batch Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing) demo is set up like this as an example.

---

If you are expecting data to be sent to the server the moment that you edit, delete, or create a row, then you should set `batch` to `false` instead. Then the DataSource won't wait for more (a batch) of changes, and will immediately send the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  //define datasource parameters as per your requirement
});
var grid = jQuery("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
});

jQuery('#changeevent').change(function()
{
  dataSource.read({
    parametername:jQuery("#valueoffeild").val()
  });

  var grid = jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
  grid.refresh();
});
```

Above code pass an extra parameter to your URL.

Comment: No need to call `grid.refresh()` at the end. `DataSource.read()` will trigger a `change` event, which will cause the grid to refresh on its own.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my other answer on DataSource `batch` mode, I also see that you are initializing 3 dropdown lists to use as editors. The Kendo Grid has a built-in feature for doing this, called [ForeignKey Columns](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn). Their demo only shows a synchronous load of the FK data to use in a dropdown editor, but I have an example that loads multiple asynchronously here:

[Kendo Music Store Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tutorials/asp.net/kendo%20music%20store/music%20store%20web/kendo-music-store-web-management-grid#using-the-foreign-key-feature-to-show-genre-and-artist-names.)

[Kendo Music Store Source (GitHub)](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store/blob/master/MvcMusicStore/Scripts/App/storemanager-index.js)

Answer (score 0):

I am using kendo-ui 2014.3.1119 and this is what I did to get kendo-ui to leverage ngResource Restful API.

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            RestService.query(function (result) {
                options.success(result);
            });
        },
        update: function (options) {
            RestService.update(options.data, function (result) {
                options.success(result);
            });
        },
        create: function (options) {
            RestService.save(options.data, function (result) {
                options.success(result);
            });
        }
    }
```